# Is there a way to 'store' Sudo temporarily

Tags: linux, terminal, passwords, redhat, sudo

I'm quite new to Linux. I remember using a tutorial were you were able to declare your sudo (+password) at the start and then use terminal without having to do sudo or import your password again.

I.e.

Sudo yum-get update -> yum-get update.

Sorry if this is a very obvious question, I honestly don't remember where the tutorial was from, and how to do it again.

ps - if it helps, I'm on a RedHat Distro, but go between Debian and RedHat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `su`. This way you are changing the ownership of the session to `root` (by default, you can also change to any other user on the system) and therefore you will be able to avoid the `sudo`.

[Here](http://www.linfo.org/su.html) you can find some more information on the command.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
sudo -i
```

It acquires the root user's environment and kind of simulates a login into the root account